# Fabric.js Textbox examples (migration from 1.6)

Tags: fabricjs

I'm migration from v1.6.2 of Fabric to the latest beta.
Once of the first things I notice is that when a Textbox is drawn, it no longer looks the same way it did before.

Here's what it looked like before:
[image]

Here's what it looks like now:
[image]

Is there documentation somewhere on how to ensure Textbox works as it did before?
Specifically, I want to ensure the same controls and skewing properties. This page doesn't contain any examples in line with my earlier UI: http://fabricjs.com/test/misc/itext.html

Comment: Can you add a snipet, how you are creating the text object?

Comment: Apologies. It turns out that with this newer version the Textbox no longer has the same default control values. I simply had to define the control settings this time.